# How to check whether a user exists in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, I am trying to check whether there is a user or not I have the following code:

```
const userExist = await User.find({ username: req.body.username });
if (userExist)
   return res.status(400).send({ message: "User already exists" });
```

but even if the user doesn't exist it still gives the error `User already exists` and the userExists object return `[]`

Comment: Use `User.findOne` instead of `User.find`

Comment: @Shahab Make sure to **use findOne**. **find** method goes through the **entire database** to find as many records as possible whereas **findOne** stops as soon as it finds the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `[]` is true in `Javascript`. You need to check the length and check if there is some data in an array.

```
const userExist = await User.find({ username: req.body.username });
if (userExist.length > 0)
     return res.status(400).send({ message: "User already exists" });
```

For future references, all the below values are truthy in JS.

```
if (true)
if ({})
if ([])
if (42)
if ("0")
if ("false")
if (new Date())
if (-42)
if (12n)
if (3.14)
if (-3.14)
if (Infinity)
if (-Infinity)
```

Note: Recommend you to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) link.

Answer (score 2):

u can use `const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });`
this get only one and u can check !user

Answer (score 2):

Another way to verify if the user exists is to use mongoose `.exist()`. If at least one document exists in the database that matches the given filter, and null otherwise

Read more here [.exists](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-exists)

`

```
 const userExist = await User.exists({ req.body.username });

  if (userExist)
          return res.status(400).send({ message: "User already exists" });
```

`